# Why doesn't this change the value

Tags: java

```
public class SubiectLicentaTrei {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        double d = 12.34;
        ScadeUnitate su = new ScadeUnitate();
        su.scadeUnitate(d);
        System.out.println(d);
    }
}

class ScadeUnitate {
    public void scadeUnitate(double d) {
        d = d - 1.0;
    }
}
```

Outputs 12.34 when I expect 11.34.

Comment: `su.scadeUnitate(d);` This passes your `double d` ***by value***.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java is pass by value

so when you pass the **here**

```
ksu.scadeUnitate(d);
```

`d` will be a `pass-by-value` and when you deduct it **here**

```
d = d - 1.0;
```

`d` wont reference the value `11.34`.
but will get destroyed when `out-of-scope`

**solution:**

put a return value of the `scadeUnitate` method

```
public double scadeUnitate(double d)
```

get the return value to reference from the returned value.

```
d = su.scadeUnitate(d);
```

Answer (score 0):

Cause `d` is primitive local variable and keeps new state only in `scadeUnitate` function. You should rework your function to return new value and reassign `d` with new value in `main` function.

Comment: @ScaryWombat are you sure it will work passing a `Double`? I've just tried it and got the same result. I think it's because of *autoboxing*.

Comment: deleted my misleading question then.

Comment: Seems that it will not work for wrapper types

Comment: There is no method for actually setting the value on a instance of `Double` - if you look at the javadocs the methods are static.  if you created your own wrapper for a primitive it should work

Answer (score 0):

In Java references to Objects, and primitives are passed by value.

```
 public class SubiectLicentaTrei {
        public static void main(String args[]) {
            double d = 12.34; // local variable `d`'s value is 12.34                 
            ScadeUnitate su = new ScadeUnitate();
            su.scadeUnitate(d);  // passing 12.34 to constructor.
            System.out.println(d);
        }
    }

    class ScadeUnitate {
        public void scadeUnitate(double d) {  // another local variable `d` (different from original one). Also `d` is of a primitive type (`double`)
            d = d - 1.0;       // the second local variable d being changed. The first d is untouched.
        }
    }
```